# Bash doesn't support `show-mode-in-prompt` readline option for `vi` editing-mode on macOS?

Tags: terminal, bash

I've played with `vi` command-line editing in Bash on Linux, and wanted to enable in macOS too, but while `vi` editing seems to be supported, I cannot get Bash to display `vi`'s mode on the command-line prompt using `show-mode-in-prompt`?

```
set -o vi
bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on'
```

Doens't Bash on macOS support `show-mode-in-prompt` readline option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show-mode-in-prompt option was introduced in bash 4.3 (from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144421/151019)) but Apple supplies version 3.2 (which is probably why zsh will become the default for new users but this old bash will remain for Catalina at least.)

So you need to install a newer version of bash. Package managers like Macports, fink, Homebrew and Nix will have a port of this.

e.g. for Macports . Install Macports as per the [guide](https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports) basically download and eun an installer from the downloaded .dmg

Install bash to /opt/local/bin by

```
sudo port install bash
```

Then add to Terminal or iTerm preferences to change the command that is ruin to be this bash explicitly.

This currently gives you bash version 5.

Comment: Thanks @Mark - What do you mean by "`zsh` will become the default for new users"? Are you saying that Apple will replace Bash? Also, will you show how to install a newer version of Bash using Homebrew alongside Apple's Bash, so that I don't mess my system up? What is Apple's reason to include such an old version of Bash?

Comment: We don;t know Apple's reason for the old bash version but it is noted that this is the last bash version licensed under GPL v 2, later ones are under GPL v 3

Comment: Thanks - it might be off-topic, but is bash about to be replaced on Linux/OSX systems by zsh, like it seems to be the case for GCC and LLVM?

Comment: @Shuzheng Absolutely not. MacOS and GNU/Linux are different. Here the difference is the license GNU's aim is improve there tools so that a Free OS is better than commercial onbes. Part of that is that GNU will keep improving bash and gcc on GNU/Linux and other OS.

Comment: Ohh, so GNU write their license, so that a commercial OS like OSX cannot use their tools?

Comment: No GNU licenced tools can be used in commercial OS. It is I suspect that Apple are not certain they want to promote the latest version of GNU. For more I think you need to ask a lawyer

Comment: @Mark Uh, that's... completely wrong.  Nothing about the GPL says you can't distribute software covered by it for profit.  Apple, though, refuses to endorse GPL3, and so will not distribute software licensed under it, such as Bash4.  ZSH is *not* licensed under the GPL, neither are tcsh or ksh, which Apple also distribute as part of the OS.

Comment: Ah sorry for bad punctuation. I meant No to Shuzheng's comment.  GPL licensed code can be used in commercial as Apple.Next have done for 30 years. Apple now seem to have decided they can't meet GPL v3.